# Similar By Terms module

Tags: drupal, module

I have a blog where you can add tags. I wanted to see the related blogposts to this **tag** in a view so i created one with the module **Similar By Terms**.

However, i can't seem to link old blog posts to new posts. Only new posts to old posts.

what does this mean? when i add a new blog i get all past blog post with the same tag posts. But when i click on them i dont see my **new** blog in the similar tags list.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running Drupal's cron?  I imagine that is how they would generate the similar terms - at least it was when I used this module in Drupal 5.

Just go to yoursite.com/cron.php and then check the old posts.

Comment: no problem. please mark as answer to help this fall out of the Unanswered queue :)